# Return anchor tag with click event from custom pipe in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I create an anchor tag dynamically, add click event that binds a method and return and show it in the td?

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'mypipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.stylize(value);
  }

  stylize(msg: string) {
      let anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchor.addEventListener('click', (event: Event) => {
        this.printMessage(msg);
      });

      let text = document.createTextNode('Click to print message in console');
      anchor.appendChild(text);

      console.log(anchor);
      return anchor;
  }

  printMessage(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

I am using this pipe in my table:

```
 <td>{{ msg | mypipe }}</td>
```

I want to get an anchor tag with msg as text and click event with printMessage() method. console.log prints anchor tag without the click event, that means click event is not binding to the anchor tag, and the returned value is not showing in table td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can insert elements through pipe in some way like `<td [innerHtml]="msg | mypipe"></td>` and return html source of element, that you want to insert. but it will be just html element with no access to your angular environment. 
The more suitable way to solve your problem is to make a simple component

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-tag',
 template: `<a (click)="handle()">{{msg}} Click to print message in a console</a>`
}) 
class MyTagComponent {
  @Input() public msg;
  public handle() {
   console.log(this.msg)
  }
}
```

usage

```
<td><my-tag [msg]="msg"></my-tag></td>
```